# Protocol for password-less authentication in clis

Tags: rest, authentication, web, command-line-interface, protocols

I have a cli (which use a rest api) which needs authentication for use.
As of right now, it supports a token auth. This token is generated at the server on a request with username and password and given as the response.This is not ideal (due to man in the middle attacks) and I am looking for a better protocol to use to generate the tokens.

Users will use such a protocol from a cli, and may or may not have access to a browser on the same device (Though a protocol that requires opening a website is not a problem)

The OAuth device flow seems to be a very simple to use flow, but it is meant
for **authorization** and not **authentication**. I also do want to support OAuth as that will require a lot of work, and frankly not what I need.

What is the standard or recommended protocol to use in such a situation?

Answer (score 0):

MITM should not be an issue if your server and app are properly securing the connection. There is nothing really wrong in using a username+password to connect to your backend services. After all, when you're logging into the site you're sending an HTTP request with your username and password to a backend the same way your cli app would do it.

But OAuth indeed can a better fit for cli app:

1. it's easier to revoke the stolen OAuth token than to force user to change a password,
2. an app doesn't have to deal with user credentials (although OAuth credentials flow is also exists),
3. it gives you flexibility when creating new tokens. For example, you may want to issue short lived tokens only to force the user to re-login each time the app is used or you may want to use long-lived refresh tokens.

As you already mentioned, OAuth doesn't handle authentication but you can use your current login flow to verify user credentials and issue an OAuth token (how exactly do that is a separate topic).

I don't think there is a special protocol targeting authentication in cli apps. In any case the app would need to send some secret to a backend. One of the possible solutions is to use OTP (e.g. SMS or email code). In this case you send the code the same way as you would send a password but it is better protected against MITM attacks because a code cannot be used more than once.